# How to nest a hash dataset when joining tables

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a `left outer join` query and I would like to nest the result when I execute the query from the `.all` method. At the moment I am only able to return the result in a flat hash but I would like a nested hash so the join table name is the next level in the hash. Is this even possible within Sequel?

I have `product` and `meta` tables and the Sequel command is via graph so the columns are aliased, and look like this:

```
db[:product].graph(:meta, {product_id: : product_id}, {join_type: :left_outer}).all
```

What's annoying with the graph command is it will only alias columns if it matches the main table. Is there a way of making sure it changes all the columns as you'll see that the `quantity` column hasn't got a prefix of `meta_`?

If this is possible then I suppose I could modify the hash manually by moving the `key => values` into a separate hash that is nested by matching the prefix (meta_) of the keys.

This is what is currently being returned but I would like the nested hash instead:

Currently:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Shave',
  product_id: 123,
  meta_id: 1,
  meta_product_id: 123,
  quantity: 2
}
```

What I'd like to see:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Shave',
  product_id: 123,
  meta: {
    id: 1,
    product_id: 123,
    quantity: 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found this question via Google. It had me stumped for awhile but I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/issues/1363) which mentions that the functionality was moved to the `graph_each` extension. This extension is included with the Sequel gem, but it is not enabled by default. You can enabled it for all datasets using `DB.extension(:graph_each)`. The [docs page](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/graph_each_rb.html) has more information.